# Twilio api parse error: unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'

Tags: php, constants, user-agent, twilio

I have PHP 5.4.21

I'm using a Twilio API that works fine from a browser but in command line mode, I get the following error:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in <b>sms/Services/Twilio.php</b> on line <b>36</b>
```

Line 36 of the specified file is part of the following class, please see my note where I specify Line 36.

I added all lines of code leading up to and immediately after Line 36 for context, based on some initial feedback requests to show these lines.

```
<?php
function Services_Twilio_autoload($className) {
    if (substr($className, 0, 15) != 'Services_Twilio') {
        return false;
    }
    $file = str_replace('_', '/', $className);
    $file = str_replace('Services/', '', $file);
    return include dirname(__FILE__) . "/$file.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('Services_Twilio_autoload');

/**
 * Create a client to talk to the Twilio API.
 *
 *
 * :param string               $sid:      Your Account SID
 * :param string               $token:    Your Auth token from
 *      twilio.com/user/account
 * :param string               $version:  API version to use
 * :param $_http:    A HTTP client for making requests.
 * :type $_http: :php:class:`Services_Twilio_Http`
 * :param int                  $retryAttempts:
 *      Number of times to retry failed requests. Currently only idempotent
 *      requests (GET's and DELETE's) are retried .
 */

class Services_Twilio extends Services_Twilio_Resource
{
    /* this is Line 36... */
    const USER_AGENT = 'twilio-php/3.12.0';

    protected $http;
    protected $retryAttempts;
    protected $last_response;
    protected $version;
    protected $versions = array('2008-08-01', '2010-04-01');

    public function __construct(
        $sid,
        $token,
        $version = null,
        Services_Twilio_TinyHttp $_http = null,
        $retryAttempts = 1
    ) {
              $_http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
                  "https://api.twilio.com",
                  array("curlopts" => array(
                      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => self::USER_AGENT,
                      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept-Charset: utf-8'),
                      CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem',
                  ))
              );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: remove comma from the end of this line maybe:                       CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem', ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 - you can have a comma at the end of an array.

Comment: @OP - It would help if you could add a note to the code to say exactly which line is line 36

Comment: The parse error remains

Comment: Can you please put all code from Line 36 and above in your sample? There's a good chance that line 35 contains the error and 36 is just what the error points to.

Comment: @andrewsi, I did - please see my comment in the code above which says specifically which line is Line 36.

Comment: @livebanchies - so you did; my apologies. Can you also add in the previous lines? There's probably an issue on one of those.

Comment: @newfurniturey and andrewsi, please see my edited code. there's really nothing else above Line 36 which is helpful, only addl lines below 36.

Comment: The line 36 is ok, we need the content before, even if you think that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @livebanchies If you cannot figure out how to resolve the error on your own, how can you say that the code is not relevant? Please submit the code *above* line 36 before we can assist you further.

Comment: @livebanchies - we really need to see the content before the line. The parser is saying that `const` is unexpected, which means that there's something before that line that isn't finished correctly - a missing semi-colon or something.

Comment: Let me reiterate: this code WORKS in a browser. It's command-line mode where this is not working.

Comment: @newfurniturey and andrewsi, I just added all lines of code for your review.

Comment: The code you posted is not the same code that's generating the parse error.

Comment: @livebanchies In the code you submitted, line 36 is `protected $version;`, a few lines below the one you commented being the correct line. Are you sure this is the correct file and/or have you omitted additional code from the sample?

Comment: The most likely explanation as far as I can see is that your command-line is running a different version of PHP to your web server. Try running `php -v` at the commandline to confirm that it's running the version you expect.

Comment: @Spudley, thank you for your feedback.  Seems like you're the only one actually reading my post and not making assumptions. As you said, I ran "php -v" and here's what I get, so it's apparent I'm running an earlier version of PHP:  PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 22 2013 09:48:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

Comment: Well there's your problem then. I'll post it as an answer, since it clearly is the root of the issue.

Comment: I get two down votes because a couple commenters want to insist on their solution to a problem that doesn't even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my original comment:

The most likely explanation as far as I can see is that your command-line is running a different version of PHP to your web server. Try running php -v at the commandline to confirm that it's running the version you expect.

*OP's response*

> @Spudley, thank you for your feedback. Seems like you're the only one actually reading my post and not making assumptions. As you said, I ran "php -v" and here's what I get, so it's apparent I'm running an earlier version of PHP: PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 22 2013 09:48:43) Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

So there we go, that's clearly the problem. You've got PHP 4.4 on there. That needs to go.

Solution get rid of the old busted version of PHP, and make sure your command line php is running the same version as your web server.

You haven't specified what operating system you're running, which will obviously make big a difference to *how* you do the un-install.

If you can find the old PHP version in your un-install tool, do it and hopefully you'll start picking up the newer PHP version by magic. If not, then depending on how things are configured you may find that the easiest wat to achieve this is to un-install *both* PHP versions, and then re-install the 5.4 version.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this is on 1and1's server so I don't have control over the php version. Just another reason to move to aws or another host.

Comment: what??? 1and1 have provided you with a server with PHP4 on it??? Yes, you need to write them a stinky email and find a better host.